# C# communicating between two listviews

Tags: c#, events, user-interface, listview, mono

I have a Frame. Inside this I keep two ListViews. Now based on the item selected in the first listview, I do some operations and populate the contents for the second listview.

I am new to C# and not able to understand what is the best way to update things. Let me show by code.

```
Class ListA : IListProvider 
{
List<string> items = new List <string> ();
 void selectionChanged ()
 {
    //view.Selected gives the selected item index in the list 
 }
}

class ListB : IListProvider 
{
   List<string> items = new List <string> ();
}

Class Shell 
{
Frame f = new Frame ();
ListA a = new ListA ();
ListB b = new ListB ();
f.Add (a);
f.Add (b);

// Now how do I get the event of selectionChanged in ListA to affect the contents of ListB

}
```

Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks.

Comment: WPF isn't implemented in Mono yet, so I guess that's WinForms

Comment: actually it is in a ncurses interface of mono. However, I believe the event model will be irrespective of the UI-framework. Won't it ?

Comment: @Sankar: of course not. The control will be different, so why would the event model be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using mono's ncurses library and it did not had this Event. So the solution was for me to create my own Event and its EventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You must to register to SelectedIndexChanged event of 1st listView.
In this event handler implement a logic of populating 2nd listView based on selection (look at eventArgs object )

I dont understand what technology you are using (winform ? wpf ? ASP ? ) but here is example for winforms :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged.aspx